# Mysql SELECT COUNT(COL) with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with some data like

```
id      group_id    f1    f2    f3
1          1        a     b   
2          1        c   
3          2        a           c
```

How can i retrieve one row with group_id and count of rows for each field satisfying some textual condition?

Like that:

```
MY_MAGIC_SELECT(`f1`='a',`f3`='c');
```

must return

```
group_id    f1    f2    f3
   1        1     0     0        
   2        1     0     1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using a sequence of `SUM(CASE...)` aggregate functions to represent each of your conditions should do it.  The `CASE` returns a 0 or 1 if the condition is matched, and the `SUM()` adds the result. The `GROUP BY` is applied on the `group_id`.

```
SELECT
  group_id
  SUM(CASE WHEN f1 = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS f1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN f2 = 'b' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS f2,
  /* f3 = 'b' isn't in your "magic select" but here it is anyway... */
  SUM(CASE WHEN f3 = 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS f3
FROM 
  yourtable
GROUP BY group_id
```

Specifically for MySQL, you don't need the `CASE` since the boolean expression `f1 = 'a'` will itself return a 1 or 0. So you can simplify it to the example below.  This is not portable to any RDBMS, however.

```
SELECT
  group_id
  SUM(f1 = 'a') AS f1,
  SUM(f2 = 'b') AS f2,
  SUM(f3 = 'c') AS f3
FROM 
  yourtable
GROUP BY group_id
```

#### [Here is a quick demonstration on SQLfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60195/2)

Comment: I'm sorry for question editing. Wanted to show all the logic. And thank you for your answer. It's fitting my question perfectly.

Comment: Also note that MySQL has the inline IF expression, which is less syntactically ugly than CASE, when you have a single condition.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Is there any way to filter the all NULL rows? i'm wandering about `HAVING f1 IS NOT NULL OR f2 IS NOT NULL OR f3 IS NOT NULL`. is there any cheaper way?
Oh, well I must mention, that I've changed SUM to MAX

Comment: @Goover That should be possible in the `WHERE` clause with `OR`s.  `WHERE f1 IS NOT NULL OR f2 IS NOT NULL OR f3 IS NOT NULL`  Rows with any non-null value will be included in the output.

Comment: That `WHERE` clause will include the rows, which may be filtered by condition in SUM() [or MAX()], or it will not?

Comment: The `WHERE` clause will filter rows out _before_ the `SUM()` aggregate is applied. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm

Comment: oh, yea.. That was a stupid question.. Both of these conditions will be applied and order doesn't matter, so ofc `WHERE` is better.. My mind is broken a little on SAT

Comment: Nope, `WHERE` is not filtering the results, so switching back to `HAVING`. Here is a bit changes in your sample http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7cdd/1

Comment: @Goover Oh I get it - I misunderstood/didn't think through your requirement.  HAVING is the way to go.  `HAVING f1 > 0 OR f2 > 0 OR f3 > 0`

Comment: _Well it might be because English is not my native language, so it is hard for me to explain the problem._ Anyway now it is working. Thank you.

@siride I'm using  the `SUM(f1 = 'a')` variant, so there is no any `IF` statements

Answer (score -2):

Well, it is simple MySQL and you need to learn this. Please check this out:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

```
SELECT column_name(s)
 FROM table_name
 WHERE column_name operator value
```

for example

```
SELECT * FROM Persons
 WHERE City='Sandnes'
```

Comment: This question is about aggregate grouping, not about limiting via a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Also, don't ever link to w3schools. The site is full of bad or wrong advice and documentation.

Comment: @siride not all W3 articles are bad, actually most of them are good.

Comment: @Andrew: there are still better sources out there, such as the actual documentation for MySQL and PHP, which also include copious examples.